# writing "%d" in a printf C

Tags: c, syntax

What is the correct syntax for this code:
is it:

```
printf("printf(\"\%d\",%s);", some_var);
```

or

```
printf("printf(\"%%d\",%s);", some_var);
```

Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one.  `%d` is defined by printf, not the C language, so you need to escape it with the printf `%%`, not a character escape.

A more complex example with a character escape sequence:

```
printf("printf(\"%%d\\n\",%s);\n", some_var);
```

Comment: lol you'll get the correct answer because you remembered me i was forgeting to put a \n in the end of my printf :P

Answer (score 3):

The second one. In order to print a literal `%` you need to escape them by appending another `%`.